# PHP: How to detect if a jpeg is completely black (no image)?

Tags: php, gd

I built a community website where the users upload their photo and they can crop the thumbnail, ala Facebook to be clear.

But for some reason some of them generate a blank (actually black jpeg thumbnail).

I tried different solutions but it sounds like this is happening with big images or maybe in computers where JS is not enabled? I don't know...

Bottom line, since the number of users with this is very tiny, I was thinking of creating a patch: detect when the user generates a blank jpeg.Then I would be able to warn them.

Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 5):

Resize it to a 1x1 PX image.  Then check if the one pixel is black.  Not perfect, but if there is a significant amount of non black in the original, that 1px will not be black. The benefit is that it will be fast.

Comment: Interesting idea, but I think it's too rough in 1x1. It's bound to create false negatives e.g. with checkerboards or black-and-white geometrical shapes. But this might work with, say, a 10x10 pixel image

Comment: @pekka true, 10x10 would probably be more accurate, and still pretty fast. A decent compromise.

Comment: @Pekka웃 an resampled (antialiased) scaled image of a checkerboard will turn out gray.

Answer (score 3):

I *think* there is no faster way than walking though each pixel using [`imagecolorat()`.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php)

As to why this happens, it could be because of [CMYK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK) JPG files that GD can't digest. Not sure - you would have to try out. If that is the reason, you could detect CMYK using [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) and its `channels` info.

Answer (score 2):

I like this random algoritm,

```
function check_if_black($src){

    $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    list($width_orig, $height_orig)=getimagesize($src);
    for($i=0;$i<20;$i++){
        $rand_width=rand ( 0 , $width_orig );
        $rand_height=rand ( 0 , $height_orig );
        $rgb = imagecolorat($img, $rand_width, $rand_height);
        if($rgb!=0){
            return "not black";
        }
    }
    return "black";
}
```

Even if 80% of the image is black it has 99% to succeed. you can also increase the loop for better percentage.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming its a valid black image you could:

long way - scan pixel by pixel for the colour black

short way (if its the same black image always) - compare file byte by byte (or md5 hash) to a sample black image

Comment: The second option wouldn't work. You would need a separate copy for every combination of width, height, compression ratio, codec...

Comment: I don't think the short way will work because ID3 header and other metadata will differ wildly all the time... But I can be wrong

Comment: wouldn't the byte count / contents differ based on file size?

Comment: @Joe @Pekka I'm assuming a fixed width/height/id3 stripped jpeg :)

Comment: @reuscam we don't know this. the short way is just an idea in case it works for OP.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

trait BlacknessCheck {

    public static function fileIsBlack($filename, $throw_error = false) {

        if (exif_imagetype($filename) === IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {

            return self::imageIsBlack(imagecreatefromjpeg($filename));

        } elseif ($isimage === IMAGETYPE_PNG) {

            return self::imageIsBlack(imagecreatefrompng($filename));

        } else {

            if ($throw_error) {
                throw new \Exception("Provided file is not an image.");
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        }

    }

    public static function imageIsBlack($image) {

        $scaled_image = self::scaleImage($image);

        $added_colors =
            imagecolorat($scaled_image, 0, 0) +
            imagecolorat($scaled_image, 0, 1) +
            imagecolorat($scaled_image, 0, 2) +
            imagecolorat($scaled_image, 1, 0) +
            imagecolorat($scaled_image, 1, 1) +
            imagecolorat($scaled_image, 1, 2) +
            imagecolorat($scaled_image, 2, 0) +
            imagecolorat($scaled_image, 2, 1) +
            imagecolorat($scaled_image, 2, 2);

        imagedestroy($scaled_image);
        imagedestroy($image);

        return ($added_colors === 0);

    }

    public static function scaleImage($image) {
        $newimage = imagecreatetruecolor(3, 3);
        imagecopyresampled(
            $newimage, $image,
            0, 0, 0, 0,
            3, 3, imagesx($image), imagesy($image)
        );
        return $newimage;
    }

}
```

I'm using it to remove black thumbs.

```
private function removeBlackness() {

    $files = $this->glob_recursive(public_path('img/collection/*.jpg'));
    foreach ($files as $filename) {

        if (self::fileIsBlack($filename)) {
            unlink($filename);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

If it's all black, the file size will be low, as it's compressed. I know JPG uses perceptual rather than RLE, but it will still be smaller. Why not disallow JPGs under 20k for example? Make a few examples, compare the sizes, set your thresholds.

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea. What I want to upload some grey mist?

Comment: Then the poster probably doesn't want you in his website anyway!

Comment: Including those with black images?

Comment: Jpeg compresses with waves. so a gradient will also result in low file size. Clouds will compress in low file size, and checkerboards will compress very well. This question is specific about black images. Probably broken images. My suggestion would be to resample the image to 1 or 3x3 pixels and add the RGB values of all the resampled pixels. Only the black image will give a result of 0.